# Distribution of functions of uniform random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, conditional-probability

Given these two independent and uniform distributed random variables, $$X \sim U[-\pi,\pi]$$ and $$Y \sim U[-\pi,\pi]$$

What is the distribution of $$\sin(X)$$ and $$\sin (Y)$$ and the distribution of $$\sin(X)-\sin(Y)$$

Thanks

Comment: If $X,Y$ are independent, then one could say something about this.  If $X=Y$ with probability $1$ (as far from independent as you can get) then one could also say something.  And with other sorts of information about the joint distribution, one could also say something.

Comment: The problem of the distribution of $Y$ is the same as the problem of the distribution of $X$; it only gives a different name to the variable.

Comment: Thanks, I know but I want the distribution of the difference of their sin that is why I defined to identical uniform random variable and yes they are independent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The number $\sin X$ is the coordinate on the vertical axis of the point $(\cos X,\sin X)$, which is uniformly distributed on the circle of unit radius centered at $(0,0)$.  Since the distribution of the coordinate on the vertical axis on the left and right halves of the circle are the same, we may as well consider only the right half, so we have the distribution of $\sin X$ with $X$ uniformly distributed between $-\pi/2$ and $\pi/2$.  This makes the sine function strictly increasing, so we can say
$$
\Pr(\sin X\le w) = \Pr(X\le \arcsin w) = \frac{(\arcsin w) - (-\pi/2)}{(\pi/2)-(-\pi/2)} = \frac{(\arcsin w)+\pi/2}\pi.
$$
The distribution of $Y$ is the same.  And so is the distribution of $-Y$, since this distribution is symmetric about $0$.  Hence the distribution of $\sin X-\sin Y$ is the same as that of $\sin X+\sin Y$.  The density for that distribution can be found by convolving the density above with itself.  Maybe I'll be back$\ldots\ldots$

Comment: Thanks, I would have to take the derivative of the above with respect to $w$ to obtain the distribution of W=sinX right? Also do you happen to have closed form of the convolution?

Comment: The derivative is routine: $\dfrac d{dw}\dfrac{(\arcsin w)+\pi/2}{\pi}$ $= \dfrac{1}{\pi\sqrt{1-w^2}}$ for $-1\le w\le 1$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Do you mean to say -$1<w<1$ instead? @Michael Hardy

Comment: @Tyrone : Actually it doesn't really matter if you include the endpoints and assign an infinite value to the density at those points.  It doesn't alter any integrals.

Comment: Should I be doing the following to find the pdf of the difference, $W=U-V=sinX+sinY$ $\int_{-1}^{1} f_{U}(w+v) f_{V}(v)dv $

Comment: Actually, you would need $\displaystyle\int_{\max\{-1,-1-w\}}^{\max\{1,1-w\}} f_U(w+v)f_V(v)\,dv$

Comment: can  you please explain to me why you have max ? I would apreciate it

Comment: Sorry: It should be $\displaystyle\int_{\max\{-1,-1-w\}}^{\min\{1,1-2\}}$.  The point is that both $v$ and $w+v$ should be between $-1$ and $1$.  ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: if  $-1 \leq w+v \leq 1$ then $-1-w\leq v\leq 1-w$, how did you get the upper limit $1-2$?

Comment: Typo: I intended $1-w$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Thanks @Michael Hardy appreciate it

Comment: a while ago you answered this question, I was hoping you give me a clear explanation why the upper limit has min while the lower limit of the integral has max?

Comment: @Tyrone : The point is that the variable $v$ should not go farther in either direction than the endpoints of the intervals in which the density is not zero.  As I said, both $v$ and $w+v$ should be between $-1$ and $1$.  To say that $v\le 1$ and $w+v\le 1$ is to say that $v\le1$ and $v\le1-w$.  To say that $v\le\text{both $1$ and $1-w$}$ is to say that $v\le\min\{1,1-w\}$.  Similarly to say that both $v\ge-1$ and $v\ge-1-w$ is to say $v\ge\max\{-1,-1-w\}$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: thanks I understand @Michael Hardy. the boundaries though do have singularity points (the function goes to zero) at the boundaries of the integral, is that not a problem?

Comment: One more question regarding the limits of the integration, as you know $-2\leq w\leq 2$, should the upperlimit be $v\leq \min(1,1-|w|)$  and $v\leq \min(-1,-1-|w|)$?